# want to print “\n” sign without getting a new line

Tags: android, string.xml

I have a string in my strings.xml in which there is "\n" sign between them

```
<string name="example">Hello\nworld</string>
```

What can I do to get the "\n" sign instead of a new line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Special characters in string resources can be backslash-escaped. So if you want to display "Hello\nworld" then you should make your string be `hello\\nworld` (notice the double backslash).

Answer (score 0):

In Code

```
String string = "abcd\nddsda";
System.out.println(string.replace("\n","\\n"));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<string name="example"><![CDATA[ Hello\nworld ]]></string>
```